# Elasticsearch conexão com servidor

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Boa tarde!

Estou tentando conectar no Elasticsearch, mas não estou conseguindo, não sei se preciso informa mais alguma coisa na classe  es=Elasticsearch(..)

```
# Import Elasticsearch package 
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 

es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'https://elk-site.....com.br','port':9200}])

print(es.info())
```

> Ocorreu exceção: ConnectionError
> ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x04EEC6B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001]
> getaddrinfo failed) caused by:
> NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x04EEC6B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001]
> getaddrinfo failed)   File
> "C:\Projetos\Ecommerce\site\Infraestrutura\ELK\Servico\Salvar.py",
> line 9, in 
> print (es.info())

Quando acesso a url ele traz os dados normal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vc está usando algum redirecionador (tipo NGINX)? Baseado no que você postou, no script Python vc está usando a porta TCP 9200 e acessando pelo browser a porta padrão, ou seja TCP 80. Alterar o script para `es=Elasticsearch([{'host':'https://elk-site.....com.br','port':80}])`

Comment: @PauloMarques erra isso mesmo vlw

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema apontando para a porta 80 e mudando o use_ssl para False.

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'elk-site....com.br', 'port': 80, 'use_ssl': False}])
```